# JTable single column selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I have a `JTable`, but I want to only select one column at a time.

I have seen `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION` etc., but that is to only select one row at a time.
I want something similar to select one column, but multiple cells in the column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I wasn't clear.
I don't want to be able to select more than one column
So multiple cells, but not from more than one column

Comment: Do you want to select complete columns or selected cells in a single column?

Comment: selected cells in a single column
So if the user was to then select a cell in a different column the selection model would remove all selections in the first column and start selecting cells from the new column

Comment: Due to the fact that you want a to select a subset of column cells rather than a full column you will have to implement a (hack-ish) `ListCellRenderer` to restrict the selected columns. See [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
```

This should be the correct answer.